# Delete multiple messages

Tags: discord.py

Well im creating a discord bot right now and i wanted to add a feature that it deletes messages.
Basically the bot waits for a message to pop up, if this message contains a given command,
in this case "sudo clean (number)", it deletes (number) messages (so if the number is 5 it deletes 5 messages). Well i mean its supposed to do that but yea its not doing what its supposed to do.

I get `discord.errors.NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10008): Unknown Message`

Thats my code:

```
elif message.content.lower().startswith("sudo clean"):
            userMessage = message.content
            message.delete()    

            for word in userMessage.split():    
                if word.isdigit():
                    textToClean = int(word)
                    for i in range(0, textToClean):
                        await message.delete()
```

Whats the Problem?

Comment: You're deleting the message that says "sudo clean xxx" and then your trying to delete it again 5 times. You can't delete a message that is already deleted.

Comment: How do i delete other message in the channel?

Comment: fetch the other messages, delete them

Answer (score -1, accepted):

here is what I use that's a lot easier if you don't want anything fancy

```
 @client.command(name="clear",
                  brief="Deletes a certain amount of messages ex. .clear 10")
async def clear(ctx, amount=5):
    amount += 1

  await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a pretty simple implementation using slash commands, which i currently use.

```
 @commands.slash_command(description='Delete messages from a channel.')
 @commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def purge(
        self,
        inter,
        amount: int
):
    """Delete a certain amount of messages in the chat

        Parameters
        ----------
        amount: The amount of messages you want to delete, can't be greater than 100
        """

    if amount > 100:
        await inter.send("Wow, take it easy, no more than 100 messages at a time", ephemeral=True)
        return

    await inter.channel.purge(limit=amount, check=lambda msg: not msg.pinned)
    await inter.send('Messages deleted.', ephemeral=True)
```

Of course, if you don't use slash commands can be easily turned into a regular prefix command

```
 @commands.command()
 @commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def purge(
        self,
        ctx,
        amount: int
):
    """Delete a certain amount of messages in the chat

        Parameters
        ----------
        amount: The amount of messages you want to delete, can't be greater than 100
        """

    if amount > 100:
        await ctx.send("Wow, take it easy, no more than 100 messages at a time")
        return

    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount, check=lambda msg: not msg.pinned)
    await ctx.send('Messages deleted.')
```

The check is for avoiding Pinned messages